# How to add another else function in php

Tags: php, html, post

Hello i need some help with php. I am trying to create a form in html and use php to verify if the password input is igual as the password2 and the email...

I already have it built but i am now trying the put an (else) at the end of the input verifier.

I always get the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\main\register.php on line 82

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$something=$_POST["something"];
$something=$_POST["something"];
$something=$_POST["something"];
$something=$_POST["something"];
$something=$_POST["something"];
$something=$_POST["something"];

if($serverSettings['register_on'] && (!isset($_SESSION['something']) && !checkInt($_SESSION['something']) && !$_SESSION['something']>=0)) {
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Registar') {
    if((checkAnum($_POST['something']) && strlen($_POST['something'])>=4 && strlen($_POST['something'])<=16) && 
    checkAnum($_POST['password'])  && strlen($_POST['password'])>=8 && strlen($_POST['password2'])<=16 && !empty($_POST['password2']) && 
    (checkName($_POST['something']) && strlen($_POST['something'])>=3 && strlen($_POST['something'])<=20) && $_POST['password']==$_POST['password2'] && 
    checkMail($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email'])<=40 && $_POST['email']==$_POST['email2'] && 
    (checkAnum($_POST['something']) && strlen($_POST['something'])>=3 && strlen($_POST['something'])<=16) && 
    (checkAnum($_POST['something']) && strlen($_POST['something'])==7)) {

        require_once("***/configfilee.php");
        mysql_select_db("ahsdsdbdi2");
        $exec="select * from account where login='$something'";
        $result=mysql_query($exec);
        $rs=mysql_fetch_object($result);
        if($rs){
            echo "<center><b><font color='#ff0000'>Registo falhou:</font> This account already exists.</b></center>";
        }
        else {
          $exec="insert into account (something,something,something,something,something,something)  values('$something',something('$something'),'$something','$something','$something','$something')";
          mysql_query("set names big5 ");
          mysql_query("set CHARACTER big5 ");
          mysql_query($exec);
            echo "<center>
            <h1><u>Registration completed successfully.</u></h1><br />";exit;
        }
    }`enter code here`
    HERE IS MY PROBLEM-> else {
      echo "<p>Something is wrong!</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

If you are having problems seeing the code here is a link to show it:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104961902/code.txt

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Use mysqli_ family (mysql improved extension) because mysql is deprecated in 5.5 versions of PHP and will be removed soon.

Answer (score 1):

Your first if statement is not closed

I think you are missing a `}` at the very end of your file.

Change this:

```
    echo "<p>Something is wrong!</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

To this (and extra `}` at the end:

```
            echo "<p>Something is wrong!</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: i closed it at the end of the page were i need it to show other things

Comment: i did what you said but it gave me an error at the end of the page but i already closed the first if at the end of the page.

    </form>  
    <?PHP
    } <-- closed if from top
    else {
    echo'<p>Registration if off</p>';
    }
    ?>

Comment: @OWSAP Well if you have already closed then you have a syntax error which is not necessarily visible around line 82. Maybe somewhere down? You'll have to show the full file for me to help out

Comment: @OWSAP I've gone through your code and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it. Im not sure why you are getting that error message.

Comment: i have been 2 days around this and i just can't see were is the problem when i put that else there but anyway thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: The answer is right you missed a `}` at the end.If it does not solve your problem modify your code again and put the right one.